# How to determine impact of a Visiting Team on Attendance at a Sporting Event? [Personal Thought Exercise]

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, causality

I am trying to figure out the impact of a visiting team on the attendance draw of a sporting event.

This is a personal inquiry exercise to see if the team that I root for has any impact on the other teams in the league.

**What I have:**

- I have all of the Attendance Reports for each event in a sports league season in a spreadsheet.
- Data Points: Date, Home Team, Visiting Team, Attendance at Event, Win/Loss

**Facts**:

- There are 12 teams and each team plays 20 home games.
- Each team's home venue has varying capacity from around 3,000 to 19,000
- Each team plays at least one home game and one away game against each other. Some teams will have two home and one away, two away and one home, or two home and two away.
- Some teams may have “sellouts”, some can have none or one; other can have many;
- Also some may classify a "sell out" as they sold their normal allocations, and then add extra tickets to more seats in the venue. (i.e. upper levels) but on the records it is a sell out.
- Sellout classification is based on the official game report indicating a sellout. For context, some teams appear to have a sellout based on attendance number but it is not marked in the official record as one.

**What I want to know**:

- Since each team/market has different maximum capacities, how to determine if there is an impact on attendance based on who the opponent (visiting team is)

Comment: Do many games sell out, so demand is censored?

Comment: @dimitriy - some games yes. some games no. some teams may have none or one, while other teams can have many.

Also some may classify a "sell out" as they sold their normal allocations, and then add extra tickets to more seats in the venue. (i.e. upper levels) but on the records it is a sell out.

Comment: Please add this new information as an edit to the post and not only as a comment! We want posts to be self-contained, and few people read comments ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen done. Thanks for the guidance.